# Report viewer in XtraReports C#.Net using Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

Hi I created three reports using XtraReports. I can able to view that in button click using this code

```
 xtrareport1 report = new xtrareport1 (Convert.ToInt32(TXE_CompanyId.Text));
 ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
 tool.ShowPreview();
```

I need to show this three reports name in LookupEdit and user select a report means need to show that preview in PrintControl1 ? How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all reports in your project then you can use the [solution](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q527498) provided by DevExpress:

> You can use the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() method to
>   get all classes defined in the assembly. Then you can cycle through
>   the list to find classes derived from the XtraReport class. To create
>   a new instance, use the Activator.CreateInstance() method.

Here is example of implementation:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var reports = new List<Tuple<string, Type>>();

    foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
        if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(XtraReport)))
            reports.Add(new Tuple<string, Type>(type.Name, type));

    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = reports;
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Item1";
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Item2";
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("Item1","Report"));
}

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = lookUpEdit1.EditValue;

    if (value == null)
        return;

    var report = (XtraReport)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)value);

    var tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
    tool.ShowPreview();
}
```