# How to display a Devexpress XtraReport on button click in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, xtrareport, document-preview

I have created a devexpress XtraReport file in my wpf application. Loaded the data into the report using custom Sql Query in Report wizard.
How can i display the report on button click in a xaml usercontrol screen?

Currently i am trying to display as below :

```
private void GenerateZBReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
    DocumentPreviewWindow window = new DocumentPreviewWindow();
    window.PreviewControl.DocumentSource = report;
    report.CreateDocument(true);
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DocumentPreviewControl](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Printing.DocumentPreviewControl) located in a UserControl or Window. This is especially helpful in case you want to customize the preview control. This functionality is described in the following help file: [Create a Custom Document Preview](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/117751/wpf-reporting/document-preview/quick-start/create-a-custom-document-preview). Otherwise you can use the PrintHelper class: [Invoke a Default Document Preview](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119217/wpf-reporting/document-preview/quick-start/invoke-a-default-document-preview).

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you've used the XtraReport class, but this class is empty.
you should
create a typed report class

```cs
new XtraReport1()
```

or load layout by calling

```cs
var report = new XtraReport();
report.LoadLayout(filePath);
```

and only after this you may assign it to viewer and call the CreateDocument() mehtod

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

```
var tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
tool.ShowPreview();
```

For more information, check this link:
[Report viewer in XtraReports C#.Net using Winforms Devexpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739007/report-viewer-in-xtrareports-c-net-using-winforms-devexpress)